# Why do I get unexpected behaviour when I use Arrays.fill() on an array of array lists?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections

I know it is not a good idea to mix up collections and arrays, but I am not getting why exactly I am getting this error.

Say,

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] x = new ArrayList[2];
Arrays.fill(x, new ArrayList<>());
x[0].add(1);
```

Why does `x` evaluate to `ArrayList[2] { [1], [1] }` now even though I am just filling index 0 with that value?

This works fine however,

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] x = new ArrayList[2];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    x[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
} 
Arrays.fill(x, new ArrayList<>());
x[0].add(1);
```

`x` evaluates to `ArrayList[2] { [0], [] }`

What exactly causes this anomaly in the first `Arrays.fill` approach?

Comment: I have just tried both these pieces of code and in both cases `x` evaluates to your first example, which is the right behavior. What is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

> `Arrays.fill(x, new ArrayList<>());`

This is misleading and doesn't do what you want.

Specifically, it does this:

1. It creates a new ArrayList instance. One instance. Just the one.
2. It then takes your array of ArrayLists, which is, of course, an array of references. It's an address book with addresses to houses, not a block of houses.
3. It then fills the entire addressbook with **the same one address**. There is still just one house. You've only made a single ArrayList.

Thus, you now have an array, where each 'slot' in the array is pointing at the exact same arraylist. Add an integer to `x[0]` and the `x[1].size()` will now return 1 as well.

The fix?

Well, you said it. Stop with this silly crud of mixing the two concepts. More generally, **you cannot use `fill` here**.

UPDATE: But there is `setAll`:

`Arrays.setAll(x, idx -> new ArrayList<Integer>());` does what you want: It invokes the thing after the array for every 'slot' in your array.

Here's a simple rule:

If you want Y objects to exist, then show me how `new Something()` is being run at least Y times. If you can't make a plausible case, guess what. You don't have Y objects.

In your fill based code, I count precisely 1 `new ....` invocation, and there is no plausible explanation available as to why somehow that one invocation is run as many times as you want (and indeed, that is the explanation: It isn't). Thus: Yup. That code doesn't do what you wanted.

Comment: [`Arrays.setAll(x, ix -> new ArrayList<Integer>());`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll-T:A-java.util.function.IntFunction-)…

Comment: /* facepalm */ Of course it's not called 'fill'. setAll's been there since java 1.8. Well, TIL. I'll update the answer, thanks @Holger!